# json file to hive external table

Tags: json, hive, hive-serde

I have data in json format.

1. Correct

[{"text":"foo0","number":123},{"text":"foo1","number":345},{"text":"foo2","number":678},{"text":"foo3","number":901}]

2. Incorrect

{"text":"foo0","number":123}{"text":"foo1","number":345}
{"text":"foo2","number":678}{"text":"foo3","number":901}

Creating  external table

```
create external table js_test_3
(
  text string,
  number string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION '/Serde'
```

Then I launch

```
select *
from js_test_3
```

As a result I get

1. Correct for  json (retrieves as many elements as there are rows)

text                                                        number

{"number":"123","text":"foo0"}                {"number":"345","text":"foo1"}

2. For incorrect json-(retrieves only first element)

text        number

foo0       123

How should I write script that creates list for which the result is correct?

text        number

foo0       123

foo1       345

foo2       678

foo3       901

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to get the json serde to correctly parse the incorrect json? You can't - you need to correct the json.

Comment: No, how to make json serde correctly parse the correct json? Wrong I will correct.
By the way, serde correctly parses the non-correct json if it's written like this:
{"text":"foo0","number":123}/n/r
{"text":"foo1","number":345}/n/r

{"text":"foo2","number":678}/n/r

{"text":"foo3","number":901}

Comment: JsonSerDe isn't expecting the entire file to be one json document, it's expecting a file with one complete json structure per line separated by CR/LF (which is why the example in your comment works correctly)

Comment: How can I solve my problem? Can eat another option solution? SERDE XML documents reads perfectly, i need the tool for JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The JsonSerDe you are using expects as input a file with one complete JSON per line. This is desirable because it is able to split the input (and divides works amongst the worker nodes) on CR/LF.

If you have a well-formed JSON list like you show in your "correct JSON" example, you could use a tool like `jq` to transform your input file into the expected format. For example:

```
jq -c .[] correct.json > /serde-input.txt
```

Comment: highlycaffeinated  Thenks